# How to use $addFields to create an array in MongoDB?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

As part of a larger problem I'm trying to use $addFields to create an array of values, and when it does not match, it yield the default value of 'none' but when it does match, it returns null. Here is a sample of the data and my current $addFields aggregation stage:

```
{ 
'_id' : ObjectId(''),
'Region' : 'Northern',
'Orgtype1' : 'A1',
'Orgtype2' : null,
'Orgtype3' : null
}
{ 
'_id' : ObjectId(''),
'Region' : 'Northern',
'Orgtype1' : 'A4',
'Orgtype2' : 'B2',
'Orgtype3' : null
}
{ 
'_id' : ObjectId(''),
'Region' : 'Northern',
'Orgtype1' : 'B5',
'Orgtype2' : 'C1',
'Orgtype3' : 'D0'
}




{ '$addFields :{
    'Affinity': {
         '$switch' : {
            'branches': [
                { case: { $regexMatch : { 'input' : '$Orgtype1', 'regex': /^A/ } }, then: {'$concatArrays' :[ '$Affinity',['A'] ] } },
                { case: { $regexMatch : { 'input' : '$Orgtype2', 'regex': /^A/ } }, then: {'$concatArrays' :[ '$Affinity',['A'] ] } },
                { case: { $regexMatch : { 'input' : '$Orgtype3', 'regex': /^A/ } }, then: {'$concatArrays' :[ '$Affinity',['A'] ] } }
                ],
                'default':'none'
        }
    },
}}
```

When I run that aggregation stage and $project the Affinity, it returns 'Affinity: none' on any object that doesn't match, but 'Affinity: null' on the objects that do match. How do I get it to create 'Affinity' as an array rather than a field/value pair?

Expected Result:

```
{ 
'_id' : ObjectId(''),
'Region' : 'Northern',
'Orgtype1' : 'A1',
'Orgtype2' : null,
'Orgtype3' : null,
'Affinity' : [ 'A' ]
}
{ 
'_id' : ObjectId(''),
'Region' : 'Northern',
'Orgtype1' : 'A4',
'Orgtype2' : 'B2',
'Orgtype3' : null,
'Affinity' : [ 'A', 'B' ]
}
{ 
'_id' : ObjectId(''),
'Region' : 'Northern',
'Orgtype1' : 'B5',
'Orgtype2' : 'C1',
'Orgtype3' : 'D0',
'Affinity' : [ 'B', 'C', 'D' ]
}
```

Comment: can you add your expected result as per these documents. if i am not wrong look at [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3nhV5llnY2i)

Comment: Ultimately there are 20 Orgtype code that will need to be matched against, and the array will have up to 3 possibles for each organization. I'm not 100% sure but I think the solution you provided will just over-write the array with a single value

Comment: can you explain how this return `'Affinity' : [ 'A', 'B' ]` in second doc, when you search for `A`

Comment: The examples given are the basics for structure, and the addFields will have to iterate through each code value, starting with A, then moving on to the subsequent ones. Eventually, organizations with the three type fields populated will have an array of [ v1, v2, v3 ], orgs with 2 would have two array elements, 1 for 1, and an empty array for organizations not having any populated. When I attempted your method, one an organization with two codes, specifically matching them, the array returned only a single value

Comment: I know the example provided is not helpful for you, ofcourse that will return one value, i am not getting your expectation, someone will help.

Comment: Understood and I'm using your example to try and solve the issue as well! Trying a few methods of iteration in order to populate the arrays

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220984/discussion-between-kevin-o-and-turivishal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to iterate through the fields to create the final array I had to first define the field as an array, then concat the results of the switch branches for each set, yielding the expected results.

Here's a condensed version of the new aggregation stages:

```
{ "$addFields" : { "Affinity" : [] } }, 
{ "$addFields" : { 
 "Affinity": {
  "$concatArrays": [ 
   "$Affinity", {
     "$switch" : {
      "branches": [
       { case: { $regexMatch : { "input" : "$Orgtype1", "regex": /^A/ } }, then: ["A"] },
       { case: { $regexMatch : { "input" : "$Orgtype1", "regex": /^B/ } }, then: ["B"] },
       { case: { $regexMatch : { "input" : "$Orgtype1", "regex": /^C/ } }, then: ["C"] }
       ],
      default : []
     }}]}}}
{ "$addFields" : { 
 "Affinity": {
  "$concatArrays": [ 
   "$Affinity", {
     "$switch" : {
      "branches": [
       { case: { $regexMatch : { "input" : "$Orgtype2", "regex": /^A/ } }, then: ["A"] },
       { case: { $regexMatch : { "input" : "$Orgtype2", "regex": /^B/ } }, then: ["B"] },
       { case: { $regexMatch : { "input" : "$Orgtype2", "regex": /^C/ } }, then: ["C"] }
       ],
      default : []
     }}]}}}
{ "$addFields" : { 
 "Affinity": {
  "$concatArrays": [ 
   "$Affinity", {
     "$switch" : {
      "branches": [
       { case: { $regexMatch : { "input" : "$Orgtype3", "regex": /^A/ } }, then: ["A"] },
       { case: { $regexMatch : { "input" : "$Orgtype3", "regex": /^B/ } }, then: ["B"] },
       { case: { $regexMatch : { "input" : "$Orgtype3", "regex": /^C/ } }, then: ["C"] }
       ],
      default : []
     }}]}}}
```

This correctly created the Affinity array and then appends the values found in each of the Orgtype columns.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal would be this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "Affinity": {
        $reduce: {
          input: [ "$Orgtype1", "$Orgtype2", "$Orgtype3" ],
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ { $substrCP: [ "$$this", 0, 1 ] } ] ] } }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      Affinity: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$Affinity",
          cond: { $ne: [ "$$this", "" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

However, I am not sure whether it fulfills your requirements. For the sample documents it works.

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L05ixGH3jGj)

or first apply the filter and then reduce:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      Affinity: {
        $filter: {
          input: [ "$Orgtype1", "$Orgtype2", "$Orgtype3" ],
          cond: { $ne: [ "$$this", null ] }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "Affinity": {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$Affinity",
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: [ "$$value", [ { $substrCP: [ "$$this", 0, 1 ] } ] ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll admit this particular solution is over my head as I've no experience with map reduce at this point. It looks more elegant than the solution I worked out so I'll have to take some time to get a working understanding of it. Thanks again